# Is there a URL for Instagram that links to user profile with user_id?

Tags: url, google-sheets, instagram, instagram-api

I have a list of user_ids (numbers) in Google Sheets and want to get the profile URL of each of these users without using import formulas since they have a lot of delay.

I have a list of Instagram user_ids (numbers) (my own followers) on Google Sheets.
I want to create a list of links that direct to each profile URL.
I can't use `instagram.com/user_id` because it is "instagram.com/username".
I can't use `i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/user_id/info/` since it directs to the information not the profile.
Importing the information as an .xml, extracting the username and then using it for the URL is really slow, since `importxml` (or other import formulas) have a lot of delay.

Is there another way to do this?

Some ideas:
- Another kind of public URL which considers the user_id instead of the username.
- A Gooogle Apps Script that transforms user_id into user profile URL.

- "instagram.com/"&A1 asks for the username, not the user_id.
- "https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/"&A1&"/info/" shows the information, not the profile.
- IMPORTDATA("https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/"&A1&"/info/") is really slow.

I expect to have a URL like `instgram.com/username` just by giving a user_id number.

Answer (score 0):

In the script editor, add this code:

```
function getuserurl(user_id) {
  var pUrl = "https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/"+user_id+"/info/";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(pUrl, options);
  var response2 = response.getContentText();
  var response3 = JSON.parse(response2);
  var response4 = response3.user.username;
  var response5 = "https://instagram.com/"+response4
  return(response5);
}
```

Then use the =getuserurl(A1) formula in the sheet, to transform an user_id (in cell A1) to a profile URL.

There might be an optimized way to do this, please if someone can correct the code, add a new answer, or I'll edit this one.